# Django + nginx + gunicorn views Increment post entry view count not updated

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

Django + nginx + gunicorn views  Increment post entry view count not updated 
when http request my post not updated. Because web server cached. BUT i not use webserver(nginx) cache .

[image]

My code worked only development version on django web server

**my code**

**views.py**

```
class ArticleDetail(EntryArchiveTemplateResponseMixin,  BaseDateDetailView):
    ...
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        Article.objects.filter(pk=self.object.pk).update(views_count = F('views_count') +1)
    ...
```

**settings.py**

```
...

CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://127.0.0.1:6379/1",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES += (
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
)

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Response of your view is cached by `UpdateCacheMiddleware` and `FetchFromCacheMiddleware`. Only the first request executes the code of your view function – and then each subsequent request after expiring the cache (see [`CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS)).

> FetchFromCacheMiddleware caches GET and HEAD responses with status
>   200, where the request and response headers allow. Responses to
>   requests for the same URL with different query parameters are
>   considered to be unique pages and are cached separately. ...

*Source:* https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache

You can disable this using `never_cache` decorator:

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.views.decorators.cache import never_cache


class ArticleDetail(EntryArchiveTemplateResponseMixin, BaseDateDetailView):
    @method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        Article.objects.filter(pk=self.object.pk).update(views_count=F('views_count') + 1)

        # ...
```